# AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer not rendering on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avfoundation, calayer

I'm struggling with AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer on iOS. I want to display a CVPixelBuffer using this layer, but i'm not able to get it work on actual iOS device. In my sample app i tried following code to display one color pixel buffer:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer *videoLayer;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    videoLayer = [[AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer alloc] init];
    videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 300);
    videoLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:videoLayer];
}

@implementation ViewController {
    AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer *videoLayer;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    videoLayer = [[AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer alloc] init];
    videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 300);
    videoLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:videoLayer];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self startVideo];
}

- (void)startVideo {
    [self drawPixelBuffer];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(drawPixelBuffer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)drawPixelBuffer {

    int imageSize = 100;

    static const uint8_t pixel[] = {0x00, 0xAA, 0xFF, 0xFF};

    NSMutableData *frame = [NSMutableData data];

    for (int i = 0; i < imageSize * imageSize; i++) {
        [frame appendBytes:pixel length:4];
    }

    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = NULL;

    CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(NULL, imageSize, imageSize, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, [frame bytes], imageSize * 4, NULL, NULL, NULL, &pixelBuffer);

    CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [self sampleBufferFromPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];

    if (sampleBuffer) {

        [videoLayer enqueueSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
        CFRelease(sampleBuffer);

    }

}

- (CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBufferFromPixelBuffer:(CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBuffer {

    CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = NULL;
    OSStatus err = noErr;
    CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef formatDesc = NULL;
    err = CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBuffer, &formatDesc);

    if (err != noErr) {
        return nil;
    }

    CMSampleTimingInfo sampleTimingInfo = kCMTimingInfoInvalid;

    err = CMSampleBufferCreateReadyWithImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBuffer, formatDesc, &sampleTimingInfo, &sampleBuffer);

    if (sampleBuffer) {
        CFArrayRef attachments = CMSampleBufferGetSampleAttachmentsArray(sampleBuffer, YES);
        CFMutableDictionaryRef dict = (CFMutableDictionaryRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(attachments, 0);
        CFDictionarySetValue(dict, kCMSampleAttachmentKey_DisplayImmediately, kCFBooleanTrue);
    }

    if (err != noErr) {
        return nil;
    }

    formatDesc = NULL;

    return sampleBuffer;

}

@end
```

This is working without any problem in iOS simulator but it's not working on real device (nothing is rendered). The video layer's error property is always nil and status is always equal AVQueuedSampleBufferRenderingStatusRendering.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 12):

The graphics implementation in the simulator is far more robust, and often you can get away with things that will not work on device. There are two common causes:

#### Pixel buffers should be backed by an IOSurface

You're mapping that buffer directly via `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes`. Try again using `CVPixelBufferCreate` with the `kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey` attribute set to an empty dictionary.

```
CVPixelBufferCreate(
    NULL,
    imageSize,
    imageSize,
    kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
    (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)@{
        (id)kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey: @{}
    },
    &pixelBuffer);
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
void *bytes = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer);
// Write image data directly to that address
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
```

In reality, whatever is generating those pixels should be writing directly into a `CVPixelBufferRef` whenever possible.

#### Devices will not support some formats

This seems extremely unlikely for `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA`, but I have seen simulator-only support with others such as `kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr8`. In these cases it must be converted to a compatible format first, or a custom renderer must be implemented (OpenGL, Metal, etc).

Comment: I had an identical problem in which AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer was not working on the device, only the simulator. By backing the pixel buffer with an IOSurface, the problem was resolved. Thank you very much for your informative answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Swift 5 version of the solution mentioned by Sterling Archer

```
extension UIImage {
func pixelBuffer() -> CVPixelBuffer? {
    let width = size.width
    let height = size.height
    let attrs = [
        kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue as Any,
        kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue as Any,
        kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey: [:],
    ] as CFDictionary

    var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
    var status = CVPixelBufferCreate(
        kCFAllocatorDefault,
        Int(width),
        Int(height),
        kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB,
        attrs,
        &pixelBuffer
    )

    guard let resultPixelBuffer = pixelBuffer, status == kCVReturnSuccess else {
        return nil
    }

    status = CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(resultPixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
    let pixelData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(resultPixelBuffer)

    guard let context = CGContext(
        data: pixelData,
        width: Int(width),
        height: Int(height),
        bitsPerComponent: 8,
        bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(resultPixelBuffer),
        space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
        bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue
    ) else {
        return nil
    }

    context.scaleBy(x: 1, y: 1)
    guard let cgImage = cgImage else { return nil }

    UIGraphicsPushContext(context)
    context.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
    UIGraphicsPopContext()
    status = CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(resultPixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

    return resultPixelBuffer
}
```